# How to download the project using the git-svn-id?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-checkout, svn-checkout

The question might seem too simple or might be irrelevant here. But i need some help immediately.

I got the git-sv-id of the library required in this link
http://code.google.com/p/vncj/updates/list

I do not know how to download such files. When i tried the svn checkout option in an empty folder it did not work

I need the files of that project. Anyone with some basic info kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is actually a git clone so you should follow the instructions as given on http://code.google.com/p/vncj/source/checkout. The git-svn-id references that you see in the commit messages suggest that the git repo itself is initialized from a svn repo, and correspond to each of the commits in that svn repo.

[image]

Comment: i tried the git clone https://code.google.com/p/vncj/
command given in the link.
It starts cloning but says fatal:HTTP request failed after 2 mins

Comment: @kairav you may need to check your configuration for your proxy/firewall and try cloning other git repos. As you can see from the screenshot I did not encounter such errors

Comment: i had a problem with the proxy.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The svn repository is located at the following URL: https://vncj.googlecode.com/svn – the following command should get you the latest trunk revision of that repository:

```
svn checkout https://vncj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk vncj-trunk
```

Comment: can you please tell me the svn command line client which has the clone command in svn
I installed the silk svn command line client and is says clone is not a valid command

Comment: @kairav: WHOOPSA, should be `svn checkout` of course … haven't used pure svn in a long time now …